# AngularDart components style behaviour tweaking

Tags: css, angular, dart, sass, angular-dart

Every html block in my AngularDart component gets a `.ngcontent-qcc0` class added, same with the CSS definitions of the component's style.scss.css
The problem is that I have content generated in the component which style directives ends getting ignored with that class addition.

- Why is that class added?
- How can I tweak that behaviour?

Comment: In angular, this is refer as the encapsulation of your component. This way your css will not spill to your other component. You can usually get around this by changing the  `ViewEncapsulation` but i'm not sure how to implement this in AngularDart.

Comment: Thank u so much, that solved my question with a brief research

Answer (score 0):

That behaviour is to make the style you code in the component to affect only the HTML in the component’s template.
As stated in [this link](https://angulardart.dev/guide/component-styles#controlling-view-encapsulation), if you gotta disable view encapsulation so this:

```dart
@Component(
  // ···
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
)
```